# Generating cross tab reports im oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, crosstab

How to query for reports like cross tab ?
For example my table looks like the following

```
+----+--+--+--+
|Name|v1|v2|v3|
+----+--+--+--+
|A   |12|10|5 |
+----+--+--+--+
|B   |10|5 |20|
+----+--+--+--+
```

Now my query should give me the following ?

```
+-----+--+--+--+
|Name |v1|v2|v3|
+-----+--+--+--+
|A    |12|10|5 |
+-----+--+--+--+
|B    |10|5 |20|
+-----+--+--+--+
|Total|22|15|25|
+-----+--+--+--+
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: MySQL or oracle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/union.html) to join rows: (MYSQL CODE)

```
SELECT name,v1,v2,v3 FROM my_table 
UNION ALL 
SELECT "total",sum(v1) as v1 ,sum(v2) as v2 ,sum(v3) as v3 FROM my_table;
```

watch it working here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/861d6/3)

Answer (score 1):

Below is similar example to your query for mysql database:

```
SELECT year, SUM(profit) FROM sales GROUP BY year WITH ROLLUP;
```

```
+----+-----------+
|year|SUM(profit)|
+----+-----------+
|2000|4525       |
+----+-----------+
|2001|3010       |
+----+-----------+
|NULL|7535       |
+----+-----------+
```